# Intellij shortcut on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a new Intellij user and I ran into some troubles with shortcuts. Despite my researches, I cannot find answers to my questions.

I'm using Intellij with an [azerty keyboard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/KB_France.svg) on both MacOS and Debian and I have strange behavior with shortcut.

- On MacOs, the shortcuts respond as if my keyboard were a qwerty. For example if I want to comment a line, the sortcut is defined as "ctrl + /", but to get that I have to type "ctrl + !", which is the location of the slash key on an english keybord.
- On Debian, the shortcuts respond fine for a french keybord, which is also annoying because the slash key isn't a primary key... I can access it on the numpad, but without numpad like on a laptop, I have to remap every shortcuts using the slash key...

I read the problem on MacOs comes from java and Jetbrain doesn't care about it at all, and it's really not a priority for Oracle.

My questions are :

- If the problem is from java, why don't I have the same problem on Debian with the same java version ?
- Why don't I have the same problem on MacOs with Eclipse also ? Do Eclipse and Intellij use different processes to get the key hit by the user ?
- Why Jetbrain doesn't provide an azerty mapping of their shortcuts ? The software is expensive and it could have the best features as possible, but if non english speaker user cannot use such a basic feature like shortcuts, it's just a big waste of money and time...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure `Intellij  | settings | keymaps` is same to get `similar keyboard shortcuts`.

Comment: Thanks for jour answer but yes this is the same sattings

Comment: 1) Intellij has a free version, so why is it expensive 2) Java does not control your keyboard layout 3) Eclipse and Intellij provide different key bindings, yes, and those are within the settings. If the keymap is not working, then Jetbrains should care about that

Comment: @cricket_007 I think you didn't understood my question, this is not about the binding but why intellij shortcut on MacOS respond like if my keyboard were a querty instead of an azerty which I use. As I read, the problem comes from the jvm, but the point is even if a free version is available, you cannot sold an IDE with such issue, even if you're not responsible...

Comment: I don't think it's JVM related at all as Eclipse is also a Java application. You can even check this reported issue... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75636

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the link I didn't saw that tread, some other put the fault on java like this one : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779 and the related jdk issue : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022079. I don't know if its java or not but I connot use intellij with this issue :( This is strange indeed since I don't have the problem on eclipse like I said in my post...

Answer (score -1):

I personally love to work with IntelliJ, I use it on both Windows (azerty) at home and on mac (us qwerty) at work. One of the things I love about this IDE is that you can completely customize your shortcuts, so If the issue still bothers you, that might be something worth considering...